# bind dependency property from custom class to UI

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

have tried for almost a hole week to find how to bind my dependency property that is in a custom class (Elements) to a simple text box,
Text inside textbox must change every time when i send particular data, this is happening for the first time only,after that, textbox want be updated ??
i have tried every single example but i could not reach my goal, here is my code :
for the class where the depency object created :

```
  public class Elements : DependencyObject
{

    public static DependencyProperty TextDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
         "TextData",
         typeof(string),
         typeof(Elements),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)
        );

    public string TextData
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextDataProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextDataProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateText(string sdata)
    {
        TextData = sdata;
    }
}
```

i have refere  to this class in xaml like so

```
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

and to use it :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Elements x:Key="myElements" ></local:Elements>
</Window.Resources>
```

the text box that need to be updated is binded to the custom class like this :

```
 <TextBox 
        Height="23" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="12,61,0,0" 
        Name="textBox1" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="237" 
        Text="{Binding TextData, Source={StaticResource myElements}}"
             />
```

what im doing wrong ?? can someone help please

Comment: Looks all ok, but how do you update the `TextData` property of the `Elements` instance in the Window's Resources (with key `myElements`)? And do you just want to show text, or do you also want to react when the user edits the TextBox text?

Comment: to update the TextData property, i have created a textbox2 and a button,inside the button click event, i instanciat class Elements and send data like so : Elements _elements = new Elements();_elements.UpdateText(textBox2.Text); the UpdateText methode update the TextData Property, and yes i just want to show text :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment: You are creating a new `Elements` object in

```
Elements _elements = new Elements();
_elements.UpdateText(textBox2.Text);
```

This is not the object that is used for the binding in

```
Text="{Binding TextData, Source={StaticResource myElements}}"
```

Change your code so that it accesses the object from the Resources:

```
var elements = (Elements)Resources["myElements"];
elements.UpdateText(textBox2.Text);
```

Then you should replace the TextBox by a TextBlock, because you only want to display text, but do not want the user to edit it.

You should also take a look at the MVVM design pattern and how it is used in WPF. There are plenty of online resources available.

Comment: Thanks Clemens,now its working, i have a little problem here, when i use a backgroundworker i cannot access TextData property  ? i get an error saying : the calling thread cannot access ... have tried Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) but with no luck,any idea please ?

Comment: Invoke or BeginInvoke is the correct way. For the details you should perhaps ask another question, but make sure you have searched StackOverflow for similar questions before.

Comment: is that the best way to set/get data for a dependencys object from a background worker??? because when i change my property from dependency to normal one, with a get and set, the data is correctly set in the TextData property, but when using the dependency's, data is not set to it,and a message error rise "calling thread Cannot access this object because ..." i still wonder why is that happening ?

Comment: This is actually happening because it's a dependency property, as opposed to an ordinary CLR property. There is however plenty of information available about this topic here on StackOverflow (and of course the rest of the web), especially about BackgroundWorker and Dispatcher.

Comment: ok , many thanks Clemens you helped me a lot ^^, one last question, how to instanciat the Elements class if we have a constructor containing 2 strings as inputs parameters : var elements = (Elements)Resources["myElements"]; how to do this with constructor having two strings as inputs

Comment: There is no constructor involved in that expression. It just gets an already existing object from a ResourceDictionary. Classes that are instantiated in XAML should have parameterless constructors and use properties for their initialization.